# Use predicateBuilder with .Where method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, predicatebuilder

Currently, I'm trying to use a LINQ expression to query a SQL database. The linq query works fine in LinqPad, however, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to form a query that will work in Visual Studio.

Here is the query in LINQPad5

```
Group_Employees.Where(x => x.EffectiveDate <= DateTime.Now && x.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && x.GroupId == 132 || x.GroupId == 134)
```

This returns 85 records (the correct number). However, when I try to use the same conditions in my C# program, I get 86 records.

My code looks like this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<TimesheetLineItem>();

                if (startDate.HasValue)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Date >= startDate);
                }

                if (weekendingdate.HasValue)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Date <= weekendingdate);
                }

                else
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.JobNumberCoding != null || x.JobNumberEquipmentGeneralLedgerDistribution != null || x.EquipmentCollection != null);
                }

                predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Timesheet.DivisionId == (int)Divisions.MPM);

                predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Timesheet.Employee.Group_Employee.Any(j => j.GroupId == 132 || j.GroupId == 134));

            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Timesheet.Employee.Group_Employee.Any(k => k.EffectiveDate <= DateTime.Now && k.EndDate >= DateTime.Now));
```

The final predicate assignment using k.EffectiveDate, etc., does not have any effect on the result set (I'm still getting 86 records instead of the 85).

Comment: Your LINQPad query seems to be missing a lot of conditions you have in your code - what about `DivisionId`?

Comment: @NetMage Thank you for your prompt response. I actually don't think that the additional conditions have much bearing on the result set. Everything up to the 2nd to last predicate (i.e. predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Timesheet.Employee.Group_Employee.Any(j => j.GroupId == 132 || j.GroupId == 134));) seems to work fine, however, when I try to filter based on the date fields, there is no effect on the result set. I feel like I need to find a way to use .Where instead of .Any for the final predicate assignment. Hopefully that makes some sense. :-/

Comment: Well, your LINQPad query also seems to be against `Group_Employees` but your predicate builder is against `TimesheetLineItem` so which are you trying to filter?

Comment: @NetMage You are right, my LINQPad query is running against Group_Employees, however, in the block of code in which the predicate is being built, I'm ultimately drilling down to the Group_Employee table and applying the conditions to the EffectiveDate and EndDate fields. This line:


                predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Timesheet.Employee.Group_Employee.Any(j => j.GroupId == 132 || j.GroupId == 134 && j.EffectiveDate <= DateTime.Now && j.EndDate >= DateTime.Now));

Does not have any effect on the result set, though I would imagine that I would have at least one less result.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: figured it out! I had to incorporate parenthesis so the following works:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Timesheet.Employee.Group_Employee.Any(y => (y.GroupId == 134 || y.GroupId == 132) && y.EffectiveDate <= DateTime.Now && y.EndDate >= DateTime.Now));
```

Thank you for your help!